# How to bind parameters via ODBC C#?

Tags: c#, parameters, odbc

I need to bind parameters on ODBC query from C#. This is the sample code, but VS tells me that there's one parameter missing.

```
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = @id";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.Int).Value = 4;
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

What is the syntax for binding values on ODBC?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Parametri insufficienti. Previsto 1.
That error tell that one parameter is missing.

Comment: ODBC does not support named params; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters.aspx it uses ordinal `?` placeholders - if your using Access is there a reason for using ODBC rather than OLEDB (which will allow them)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Odbc cannot use named parameters. This means that the command string uses placeholders for every parameter and this placeholder is a single question mark, not the parameter name.

[OdbcCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Then you need to add the parameters in the collection in the same order in which they appear in the command string

```
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE id = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.Int).Value = 4;
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You have also another problem, the USER word is a reserved keyword per MS Access Database and if you want to use that as field name or table name then it is required to enclose every reference with square brackets. I strongly suggest, if it is possible, to change that table name because you will be hit by this problem very often.

Comment: this is shameful !! how am I supposed to write portable database code ?

Answer (score 15):

use `"?"` in place of `@` if you are using ODBC.

Try to do as follows:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.Int).Value = 4;
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: And what if you will have a few params ? '@id', '@firstName' and '@lastName'? How to specify correct order of '?'

Answer (score 1):

To use ODBC parameterized LIKE carry out as follows, i.e. you do not use the typical single quotes or even put the % in the CommandText (Furthermore I think perhaps the %? has a special meaning for Oracle? :

```
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE name LIKE ?";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fieldName", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + nameFilter + "%";
```