# Insert datetime parameter to access datebase ODBC

Tags: c#, datetime, odbc

I try insert datetime value to access database but always get me error;

my source code :

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblProcessed (name, comment, file_name, seven_zip_name, mode, device_ID,send_date) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", comment);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Filename);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", sevenZip);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", mode);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", iddev);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("",dati); //when i remove this line wont get any error
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and always get me error :

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in
>   criteria expression."}

All field type is string except `send_date` field ...
when I remove `send_date` field every thing work correctly

How I insert datetime value to `send_date` field ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c

Comment: i change to 
`               cmd.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = name;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = comment;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = Filename;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = sevenZip;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = mode;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = iddev;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dati;
        `
not wotk

Comment: what about parameter names?

Comment: What are parameters values for this query?

Comment: all values is string except send_date is DateTime

Comment: What is the value of `dati` exactly? And don't use `AddWithValue` anymore. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I ran into the same problem and this is how I solved it.

I was using the "AddWithValue" and I could only get it to add a straight date, but I wanted the time portion also.

Try

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@send_date", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DateTime.Parse(dati.ToString());
```

From what I read elsewhere, the add is having problems with the milliseconds part of the date, and it looks like this method must strip them off.