# String Parameters not working when using MySql over Odbc

Tags: c#, mysql, ubuntu, mono, unixodbc

I am using Mono/C# with ADO.NET and unixODBC with libmyodbc to connect to a local MySql Server on a x64 Ubuntu Server.

The relevant part of /etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[Default]
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
```

Connecting using a DSN and querying / updating / inserting works well, with one exception:
When I try to use a query with a parameter thats a string in c# and varchar type in MySql, it does not work: the query is executed as if I had passed an empty string as a parameter.

This only happens with string as parameters - If I encode the string value inside the query string myself, the query works as expected. But to guard against SQL injections, I need to use parameters.

So the following code works:

```
string name = "test";
...

using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("delete from Table1 where Table1.Name = " + name, conn))
{
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but not:

```
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("delete from Table1 where Table1.Name = ?", conn))
{
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OdbcType.VarChar, name.Length).Value = name;
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If the type of the parameter is not a string, so for example an Integer, the inline string as well as the parameter version work as expected.

Another interesting point:
if I use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
```

an OdbcException with an Memory allocation error is thrown (that is why I set the type OdbcType.VarChar explicitly, setting the Size makes no difference)

Any pointers are appreciated - Thank you!

Take care,
Martin

Comment: Why are you using the "?" in the odbc command?
I would expect to see the @name in its place...

Comment: OK. I got it. Odbc uses it as a placeholder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c/18082957#18082957