# MS-SQL Stored Procedure doesn't work with empty params

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a form with inputs 'name' and 'phone'.

When they have values, everything works: a record is inserted into the database using a stored procedure, spFoo:

```
String sp = "spFoo 'test name','test phone'";
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sp, connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
connection.Open();
Response.Write(command.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
```

- Works on application
- Works on Mgmt Studio

But when they don't have values I get -1 as a response in the application:

```
String sp = "spFoo '',''";
```

- Does not work in application (-1)
- Works on Mgmt Studio

I want the user to be able to create a record without any input.

Why does this work in management studio, but not on the application?

*Update:* I added defaults to the params in the stored procedure, it didn't work; I gave empty strings "NULL" as values in the code, still no luck. Is this a server setting or something that won't allow empty variables?

Comment: modify sp so that param works as optional paramter, then directly call sp from code

Comment: Because you set command text to the name of the procedure. Then you need to add parameters to your command for each parameter.

Comment: What's in the procedure? And how table structure is? First, Are you use default value as nulll if value of variables not passed through procedure. And Does your table allows NULL values in case of insert.

Comment: Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your stored procedure? If so, you should remove it as it will prevent SQL Server returning the count of affected rows from the SP.

Comment: That's it! I removed that and started getting 1 back. When I checked the database, I had a bunch of empty records. I guess it takes a while for the server to tell me it has a new record. Make that an answer and I'll give you credit, @petelids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` from your stored procedure.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189837.aspx):

> Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set.

As others have pointed out you should parameterise your query too but the `-1` is caused by `NOCOUNT` being `ON`.

**Edit**

I realise it's not what you're asking but to use a parameterised query with ODBC you need to use `?`'s as ordinal place holders as per the documentation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310130). For example:

```
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    string sp = "{call spFoo (?, ?)}";

    using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sp, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        connection.Open();
        //the order here is important, the names are not!
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "test name";
        command.Parameters.Add("@phone", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "test phone";

        Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding variables via parameters did not work for me because I'm using OdbcCommand. And I'm using Odbc because that's the only way you can use a DSN. The closest I got was using question marks instead of @var_name, and even that did not work. I had to revert to adding the params directly in the commandText.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling a stored procedure from code, you should use the Parameters property on the command. Try this:

```
String sp = "spFoo";
command.Parameters.Add("@name", "test name");
command.Parameters.Add("@phone", "test phone");
```

Comment: That broke it even worse: procedure or function 'spFoo' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied.

Comment: @TravisHeeter that's because you need to add a parameter named `@name` to your stored procedure.

Comment: My stored procedure: INSERT INTO spFoo (name,phone) VALUES (@name,@phone). I got past the "spFoo expects" error though, and am still getting a -1.

Comment: @TravisHeeter I hope your table name is not the same as your stored procedure name.

Answer (score 0):

As JimmyV said, you should use the command.Parameters.Add method to setup your parameters, passing in null whenever a parameter value is not specified. To address your comment about the error 'procedure or function 'spFoo' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied', you'll also need to modify your stored procedure to use default values when a param is not supplied (e.g. null):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure
    @foo int = null
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

Sorry for not adding this a comment on the above post. Not enough reputation!

Comment: Tried all that, still doesn't work. I feel like everyone is talking about what I "should" be doing and ignoring the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling a stored procedure the way that you currently are. You should be using parameters. Your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

**Never string concat user inputted values.**

What you should have, is a stored procedure setup similarly:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE spFoo
    @name varchar(50) = 'Jim', -- default
    @phone varchar(50) = null -- optional
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- INSERT STATEMENT

END
GO
```

And then supply the parameters in the code:

```cs
string name = this.nameTextBox.Text;
string phone = this.phoneTextBox.Text;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    name = null;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phone))
    phone = null;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"<connection string>");

using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // leave this as the stored procedure name only
    command.CommandText = "spFoo";

    // if name is null, then Jim gets passed (see stored procedure definition)
    // if phone is null, then null gets passed (see stored procedure definition)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you used the Odbc namespace objects since it sounds like you are using MS-SQL. You should be using objects from the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

---

The answer to your actual question would most likely involve executing a script (not a stored procedure) similar to:

```sql
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @name varchar(50)
DECLARE @phone varchar(50)

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = spFoo
   @name,
   @phone
GO
```

**Which is not recommended.**

Comment: OK, I rewrote my entire function and Stored Procedure and I'm still getting a -1 back. I now have exactly what you have written here (the longer version, not the script). Edit, although I did not try SqlClient yet. I don't think you can use a dsn with SqlClient.

Comment: Tried SqlClient, sure enough, can't use a dsn with SqlClient.

Comment: In case you were wondering, you can't use parameters the same way in odbc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c