# Storing image in database C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have problem saving an image into mediumblob (database). I am just wondering why when I look up into my return the directory of picture that I want to save is complete like this `C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Hydrangeas.jpg`

After I store it into mediumblobs (in database) it becomes `C:UsersPublicPicturesSample PicturesHydrangeas.jpg` the `\\` disappears after I store it into the database.

This is my code so far:

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();          
open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";

if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    images = open.FileName;
}
```

The image holds the directory which is string.

This is for inserting

```
public void NewEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString;

    con.Open();

    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("insert into Employee_Tbl(Employee_No,Emp_Lastname,Emp_FirstName,Emp_MI,Emp_Position,Emp_Username,Emp_Password,Emp_Image) values ('" + employee.EmployeeID + "','" + employee.LastName + "','" + employee.FirstName + "','" + employee.MI + "','" + employee.Position + "','" + employee.Username + "','" + employee.Password + "','" + employee.Image + "') ", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Try using a parameterized query. I suspect the slash is treated as an escape character.

Comment: @shampoo use parameters like in snippets in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c

Comment: Access violation was unhandled.