# Hive ODBC Parameterized query

Tags: c#, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Wanting to run a query in a C# application against hive.

```
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("?id", OdbcType.Int).Value = 4;

OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But end up getting an error from the ODBC driver

> ERROR [HY000] [Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis
>   error thrown in server while execurint query. Error message from
>   server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line
>   1:42 cannot recognize input near '?' '' in expression
>   specification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c

Comment: @Chad thanks. I saw that but that doesn't seem to solve the issue (unless I screwed up). I am questioning if the driver even supports parameterized queries.

Comment: this is incorrect `cmd.Parameters.Add("?id", OdbcType.Int).Value = 4;` you should try it like this 
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.Int).Value = 4;`
[ODBC Parameter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: We tried it both ways @id and ?id and it still does not work.

Comment: @KevinVasko did you figure this out yet? we ran into the same problem?

Comment: @hngdev unfortunately I did not. I posted this question on Hortonworks website as well and only got the same suggestions. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/36773/hive-odbc-parameterized-query.html I think we ended up going a different path.

Comment: @KevinVasko I saw your question on that site, I'm thinking of using stored procedure on Hive. Not sure it's going to work.