# Why is parametrization via ODBC C# not binding?

Tags: c#, odbc, parameterized

I have find this [How to bind parameters via ODBC C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c) example of how parametrization via ODBC in C#, but in my code CommandText stays with "?" and returns error - whitch is expected.

Here is my code:

```
string variable = SVariablaKlas.ToUpper(); //this is simple var like 123

Conn odbc = new Conn();
odbc.db.Open(); //this works fine -> connection is established

OdbcCommand dbCommand = odbc.db.CreateCommand();
dbCommand.CommandText = "";

if (a)
{
  dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT col1 FROM TableName WHERE ID = ?";
} else if (b)
{
  dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT col2 FROM TableName WHERE ID = ?";
}

dbCommand.Parameters.ADD("@ID", OdbcType.Char).Value = variable;
//or if I try this: ...Parameters.ADD(new OdbcParameter(string.Empty, variable);

OdbcDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

...
```

In both my cases of "Parameters.ADD", my dbCommand.CommandText would be "SELECT col1 FROM TableName WHERE ID = ?" and then I would get error: ERROR [HY000] near "WHERE": syntax error (1)

Any idea where is problem?

For database I am using SQLite3 and ODBC driver SQLite3 ODBC Driver, version 0.9993.00.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL should be

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT col2 FROM TableName WHERE ID = @ID";
```

since your parameter is named as "@ID"