# C# not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if a username with the given passwort exists in my database, if it exists it should return true otherwise it should return false.

My current function looks like the following:

```
public bool user_check(string username, string password)
{
    string query = "SELECT username, password from swear_tool where username='" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

But I receive the following error message:

> Error CS0161 'database_connector.user_check(string, string)': not all
>   code paths return a value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What gets returned if `OpenConnection` doesn't return `true`, for example?

Comment: When returning, anything below it will get ignored. so you'll also get a error saying code can't be reached at the last two lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `return false;` at the end. Also you don't need the `else return false` in the inner if

```
public bool user_check(string username, string password)
{
    string query = "SELECT username, password from swear_tool where username='" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";

    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also see that if you have records then you return `true` and never close your connection and object. Maybe do this instead:

```
public bool user_check(string username, string password)
{
    string query = "SELECT username, password from swear_tool where username='" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";

    bool hasRecords = false;

    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                hasRecords = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
    return hasRecords;
}
```

last thing: look into [Parameterized Queires](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) to avoid SQL Injections

Answer (score 2):

Just add a return false at the end of the method:

```
public bool user_check(string username, string password)
{
    string query = "SELECT username, password from swear_tool where username='" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
    return false;  //<<---- This is where it does not know what to do if any above conditions fail.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if this check returns false:

```
 if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
```

You exit without returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

[Error CS0161](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cz4k9t.aspx) occurs when a function that specifies a return type in its signature contains a path through the function that does not return a value. In your case your function does not return a value when the `this.OpenConnection()` method returns `false`.

To prevent this error from being reported by the compiler, all paths should return a value:

```
public bool user_check(string username, string password)
{
    string query = "SELECT username, password from swear_tool where username='" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**I take this opportunity to let you know about SQL injection**

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection because you're concatenating user input into your query. You're encouraged to use parameterized queries, for more information about this topic check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c)

Comment: your code will still get the exception.. you forgot the case where it won't enter the `OpenConnection == true` if

Comment: @GiladGreen It was my intention to place the return false there as I typed in the body of my answer, but forgot to actually add it to the code. Thank you for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are writing your `return` inside `if` `while` blocks only.Besides I suggest you use parameterized query

```
public bool user_check(string username, string password){
    string query = "SELECT username, password From swear_tool Where "+
                   "username=@uname and password=@password";
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true){
        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection)){
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",usename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",password);
            using(MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
                if (dataReader.HasRows){
                    while(dataReader.Read()){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.CloseConnection();                    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Nice and Clean and Safe and Shorter

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer do not close the connection when a user exists.
Try this:

```
    public bool user_check(string username, string password)
    {
        string query = "SELECT username, password from swear_tool where username='" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";

        if (this.OpenConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dataReader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (dataReader.Read())
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```