# IN Operator in OLEDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I am using OLEDB connection to read data from excel files. I am facing issues while using IN operator in the Select query. 
Below is my query,

```
string EmployeeIds = "'1231','1232','1233'";
SELECT [Employee Number],[Employee Name],[First In Time],[Last Out Time],[Total Work Hours] 
FROM [Sheet0$A2:J] 
WHERE  [Employee Number] IN (?);

 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",EmployeeIds);
```

I am getting empty results but if I give only single value then I am getting result. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

```
where someval in ('123,456,789')
```

is **very different** to:

```
where someval in (123,456,789)
```

The second line tests `someval` against 3 numeric values; the first line tests `someval`against a **single string value** that happens to contain numbers and commas (but those numbers and commas are irrelevant).

You cannot do what you want without (one of):

- writing the SQL dynamically to have one parameter per value, i.e. `in (?,?,?,?)`
- making use of some feature of the backend to do the split - for example `STRING_SPLIT` in recent versions of SQL Server (this will be very backend specific); I do not know enough about Excel to advise on whether such a feature exists

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common mistake.
The `IN` operator expect a **list of values**, but you are supplying a **single value** that happens to contain a list.
You should create a different parameter for each value in the EmployeeIds list.

Here is one way to do it:

```
string EmployeeIds = "'1231','1232','1233'";
var values = EmployeeIds.Split(',');

using(var command = new OleDbCommand())
{
    var sql = "SELECT [Employee Number], [Employee Name], [First In Time], [Last Out Time], [Total Work Hours] "+
              "FROM [Sheet0$A2:J] "+
              "WHERE [Employee Number] IN (";

    for(int i=0; i < values.Length; i++) 
    {
        // Please note that string interpolation will work only with c# 6 or later.
        // If you are working with vs 2013 or earlier, use string.Format instead.
        sql = $"{sql} @{i},";
        command.Parameters.Add($"@{i}", OleDbType.Int).Value = values[i].Trim(new char[] {'}); // You don't need the ' anymore since you are working with parameters now...
    }

    command.CommandText = sql.TrimEnd(',') +");";
    command.Connection = con;
    using(var reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // do your stuff with the data
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Something to make it better: Use a List to store the parameters placeholders (and they should be a "?" because we don't know the underlying db) and build the final query just using string.Join instead of many string operations (with a lot of parameters it could be a performance issue), also parameters are of type OleDb.Int32 but the op uses strings. This could work or not depending on the engine. Better do the proper thing and convert them

Comment: @Steve you mean like [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471904/3094533)? I actually thought about it but decided it would be kind of plagiarism, and though it's the sincerest form of flattery I think I better leave credit where credit is due :-)

Comment: Ah That's where it was. Perhaps we should close this as duplicate then, but it is not possible. Pretty sure there are others duplicates around

Comment: Yes, you are probably correct, [however....](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)