# Save Byte[] in odbc with c#

Tags: c#, odbc

i need help with a little problem.

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
    Template.Serialize(fingerprintData);
    fingerprintData.Position = 0;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);
    HL.RegistroHuella(ComboBx, LabelMs, bytes);
}
```

This is the save button...

```
public void RegistroHuella(ComboBox ComboBx, Label LabelMs, Byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        string hola;
        ConexionHuella();
        hola = ComboBx.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
        DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM HUELLAS WHERE ID = " + hola + "";
        DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (DbReader.Read())
        {
            LabelMs.Text = "El estudiante ya existe en la base de datos";
        }
        else
        {
            DbReader.Close();
            DbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO HUELLAS VALUES('" + hola + "','" + bytes + "')";
            DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (DbReader.RecordsAffected > 0)
            {
                LabelMs.Text = "El estudiante ha sido registrado correctamente.";
            }
            else
            {
                LabelMs.Text = "Hubo un problema al momento de registrar a este usuario.";
            }
        }
        DbConnection.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //LabelMs.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

The problem is the next... When i pressed the save button, the code generates a register in my odbc but in the field "Huella" didn't insert well.

The image: -> [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OQfZ.png)

Comment: You inserted the value of byte[].ToString(), that happens when you use the + operator.  Google "dbcommand insert bytes" for hits, several existing SO posts talk about it.

Comment: Nop, this solution is in sql. I use odbc.

Comment: @JuanMolina - the .Net database commands for the various databases are very similar (by design). So while that solution is not a 100% fit, you might be able to adapt it (Use a `Db` prefix instead of `Sql`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the [SQL Injection vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon) in your code will also solve the problem with inserting the image data.

You should avoid storing connection and command objects in fields. Instead, they should be created as local variables, and wrapped in `using` statements to ensure that their resources are always cleaned up.

If you can't move the `DbConnection` field to a local variable yet, then you should call its `Close` method in a `finally` block.

You shouldn't call `ExecuteReader` on a command that isn't going to return any records - `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` commands. Instead, call [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery), which returns the number of rows affected.

You also don't need to call `ExecuteReader` to test whether a record exists. Just select the ID of the first matching record, and use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar) to return that value.

```
public void RegistroHuella(ComboBox ComboBx, Label LabelMs, Byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        int hola = ComboBx.SelectedIndex;

        ConexionHuella();

        using (var command = DbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM HUELLAS WHERE ID = ?";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hola", hola);

            if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)
            {
                LabelMs.Text = "El estudiante ya existe en la base de datos";
                return;
            }
        }

        using (var command = DbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO HUELLAS VALUES (?, ?)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hola", hola);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bytes", bytes);

            int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (recordsAffected > 0)
            {
                LabelMs.Text = "El estudiante ha sido registrado correctamente.";
            }
            else
            {
                LabelMs.Text = "Hubo un problema al momento de registrar a este usuario.";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //LabelMs.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        DbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

**NB:** The `OdbcCommand` [doesn't seem to work with named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082957/124386). You have to use `?` as the parameter placeholder, and ensure that the parameters are added to the collection in the same order as they appear in the query.

Comment: Thx, i tried your solution but i get errors in the parameters. https://imgur.com/a/PtVQ3

Comment: @JuanMolina: That error seems to be saying there are too few parameters being passed. Which line is it thrown from? *(Check the `ex.StackTrace`, or comment out the `catch` block and debug the code to see where it stops.)*

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QgD94

Comment: @JuanMolina: Ah, OK; you're using ODBC, which [doesn't seem to like named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082957/124386). You'll probably need to use `?` as the placeholder instead. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I need to use int because is an identification and i need an image. I tried but  i get errors in the parameters

Comment: @JuanMolina: What errors?

Comment: few parameters.

Comment: @JuanMolina: On which line?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/StWgaKs.png - https://imgur.com/a/8LeFy

Comment: @JuanMolina: As I said previously, ODBC doesn't support named parameters. You need to use `?` as the parameter placeholder within the command text. See my updated answer.

Comment: oh, i undestand. I have another error different with the parameters https://imgur.com/a/yc16r

Comment: @JuanMolina: Sounds like a mis-match between the column and parameter data types. Try specifying the `OdbcType` and size for each parameter.

Comment: Thx you, i solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

1st  [USE PARAMETERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements), it is very important.

**EDIT: (based on Richard Deeming comment)**

```
DbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO HUELLAS VALUES(@param1,@param2)";                
DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1",OdbcType.Text).Value = hola;
DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@param2",OdbcType.Image).Value = bytes;
int result = DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (result> 0)
{
   LabelMs.Text = "El estudiante ha sido registrado correctamente ";
}
else
{
   LabelMs.Text = $"Hubo un problema al momento de registrar a este usuario";
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i have an error in parameters. https://imgur.com/a/IVudS

Comment: @JuanMolina, see my edit

Comment: I doubt you want a separate `INSERT` for every byte in the array! A single `INSERT` will do.

Comment: i tried again but i have another error. https://i.imgur.com/G0wM9Uh.png
Translate: error to convert the parameter value Byte to Byte[]

Comment: @JuanMolina, use my edit, don't use a foreach loop

Comment: i tried but i get problems with the parameters because i use odbc, not sql. I change with...
DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = hola;
DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@param2", OdbcType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;
And i get errors in the parameters

Comment: @JuanMolina, Edited, See my edit

Comment: the same https://imgur.com/a/2saag