# PSQL can't add value to parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, psql, readability, pervasive

I'm trying to wirte a PSQL query that somewhat easily readable, so I want to use the PsqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue() function, but I have some problem with that...

Here is my code:

```
PsqlConnection connection = new PsqlConnection(connectionString);
PsqlCommand cmd = new PsqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();

cmd.CommandText = @"
    INSERT INTO Table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field111, field12)
    VALUES (@Field1, @Field2, @Field3, @Field4, @Field5, @Field6, @Field7, @Field8, @Field9, @Field10, @Field111, @Field12)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field1", someValue1)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field2", someValue2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field3", someValue3);
...
...
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field12", someValue4);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

But I get an error that says: Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlException: 'Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.Lna.k: [LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Error in expression: @Field1 '

I tried it on some other way, which was this one:

```
PsqlConnection connection = new PsqlConnection(connectionString);
PsqlCommand cmd = new PsqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();

cmd.CommandText = @"
    INSERT INTO Table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field111, field12)
    VALUES (@Field1, @Field2, @Field3, @Field4, @Field5, @Field6, @Field7, @Field8, @Field9, @Field10, @Field111, @Field12)";

PsqlParameter field1 = new PsqlParameter("@Field1", PsqlDbType.VarChar, 12);
PsqlParameter field2 = new PsqlParameter("@Field2", PsqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
PsqlParameter field3 = new PsqlParameter("@Field3", PsqlDbType.VarChar, 1);
...
...
...
PsqlParameter field12 = new PsqlParameter("@Field12", PsqlDbType.VarChar, 1);


cmd.Parameters.Add(field1).Value = someValue1;
cmd.Parameters.Add(field2).Value = someValue2;
cmd.Parameters.Add(field3).Value = someValue3;
...
...
...
cmd.Parameters.Add(field12).Value = someValue12;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

But I get the same error :(
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What type of database are you connecting to?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It's Pervasive SQL

Comment: try using `:` instead of `@` in parameter names. Like `:Field1`, `:Field2`,  `:Field3`  etc.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I didn't use `?` but I tried it, no success, with that and neither with `:`... I tried it with `$` and now it says something else, it says: `[LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Error in expression: INSERT INTO Table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field111, field12) VALUES (<< ??? >>$Field1'`  Any ideas?

Comment: Other thing you can try is to use just `?` instead of parameter names and also add parameters with name `?` in command with values in the same order as they are expected in the query.. As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082840/how-to-bind-parameters-via-odbc-c

Comment: It seems like that's the way to do it! :D
If I change the query to this `cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field111, field12) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";`

I can add values to the parameters like this:
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Field1", someValue1);`

Thank you! :D

Comment: Pervasive only uses the `?` for parameters.  You can't use the `@` or `:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pervasive databases use `?` as a parameter, nothing else.
For example:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (name, number, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", stringName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("number", integerNumber);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(null, dateTimeDate);
```

### **IMPORTANT!**

As you can see at the 3rd example, you can use `null`, as an identifier for the variable. That's because the **order** is important and the identifier is arbitary.