# Save record in database and get its referance immediately in C# and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, visual-studio

I have point of sale system i am working on. C# and MySQL. As I capture a new sale I want to use two tables namely sale and sale_item.

the sale table has the major details of the sale, whilst the sale_item has the individual products being bought with the actual sale as a foreign key.

On clicking save, How do I create a sale record and immediately get its reference to add it on the sale product.

I thought of `select max(saleID)` but there should be a better way to go about it.

Comment: Have a look at `SELECT @@IDENTITY`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405910/get-the-id-of-inserted-row-using-c-sharp