# Get the id of inserted row using C# with thread safe

Tags: c#, mysql

In this question [Get the id of inserted row using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405910/get-the-id-of-inserted-row-using-c-sharp), some comments mention that last_insert_id/LastInsertedId is not thread safe, then what is the thread safe way? Is transaction like bellow enough?

```
MySqlTransaction tr = mysqlcon.BeginTransaction();
MySqlCommand cmd=new MySqlCommand("insert ...", mysqlcon, tr);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long id = cmd.LastInsertedId; 
tr.Commit();
```

Comment: Did you read the other comment about shared connection? That is the whole point

Comment: You will be fine unless you are running your application with many different threads and a single connection.  But if you are running insert statements on different threads and are using a shared connection the last inserted id could be overwritten due to another thread running an insert query before the last thread finished its request for the last inserted id.

Comment: @SirRufo I implicitly mean that the connection is shared

Comment: @jgetner Then the anwer is no? Non-shared connection is the only way? I use shared connection since non-shared means a thread pool with connection on each thread which I'm not familiar with. In my there are jobs pending to be done by a thread, not some fixed threads.

Comment: Well but sharing the connection is not thread safe. You have to take care that only one thread is **using** the connection.

Comment: @SirRufo Then thread pool with their own connection is the only choice

Comment: It is the same with your family car. Some of you are sharing one car, but only one of you can drive the car and all others have to **wait** for the driver to finish driving before they can drive ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo Got it, now it is an object lock problem, not a MySQL problem. Transaction is for contentions cat you can't control in-process.